# Confused why passing char** by reference isn't working as expected

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I'm relearning C at the moment and wrote the small piece of test code while reviewing pass by reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void distort_flags_list(char*** flags);

int NUM_FLAGS = 2;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    distort_flags_list(&argv);

    for (int flag_offset = 0; flag_offset < NUM_FLAGS; flag_offset++) {
        printf("%s\n", *(argv + flag_offset));
    }

    return 0;
}

void distort_flags_list(char*** flags)
{
    char* tester[2] = {"first", "second"};
    *flags = tester;
}
```

I'm curious why when running this, I get the following output:

```
first
(null)
```

rather than it printing "first" and "second". To my understanding when passing the pointer to `argv` into `distort_flags_list`, you're changing the place where the pointer points to the address of `tester` as defined within that function.

Any explanation for why this happens?

Comment: There is no pass by reference in C, only pass by value.

Comment: You're passing a pointer to a local variable (`tester`) from inside a function to its caller. This is a red flag. You're using pass-by-reference correctly, but the value you pass by reference points to reclaimed memory on the stack, so the address of the pointer to `"second"` is getting overwritten with `0` surreptitiously.

Comment: @Gopi Ref. [Call By Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value)

Comment: @ericbn In C, passing a pointer by value can be used to implement pass-by-reference

Comment: @MattMcNabb "Used to implement [something similar]". Thus, "is not". Specifically Call-by-Reference means that *re-assignment* of the parameter itself affects the calling bindings. Modifying a memory location can emulate the behavior, but it is *still* Call-by-Value (where a variable/mutable memory location is supplied as a pointer value).

Comment: @user2864740 I disagree with your terminology

Answer (score 2):

In the function `distort_flags_list`, you are setting the value of `*flags` to a value that is not valid once the function returns.

Accessing anything from `argv` after the call to `distort_flags_list` is undefined behavior.

To make sure the value `*flags` continues to be valid after the function returns, you'll need to use dynamic memory allocation.

```
void distort_flags_list(char*** flags)
{
    *flags = malloc(2*sizeof(**flags));
    (*flags)[0] = malloc(20); // Make is large enough
    (*flags)[1] = malloc(20); //  ditto
    strcpy((*flags)[0], "first");
    strcpy((*flags)[1], "second");
}
```

And then, add code to deallocate memory in `main`.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    distort_flags_list(&argv);

    for (int flag_offset = 0; flag_offset < NUM_FLAGS; flag_offset++) {
        printf("%s\n", *(argv + flag_offset));
    }

    free(argv[1]);
    free(argv[0]);
    free(argv);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Should I be using `malloc` within `distort_flags_list` to reserve space in memory for `tester`?

Comment: @Ryan, if you want the pointers to be valid even after the function returns, then the answer is yes. You need to use `malloc` to allocate memory. Of course, then you'll have to add calls to `free` to deallocate the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Local variable cannot be used outside the function blocks .You can use above method or you can make use of keyword `static`.

```
static char* tester[2] = {"first", "second"};
```

So that `tester` holds its value till end of program.

see demo here -https://ideone.com/eLDn3m